# Facebook F8: Mem Models Concept

Tags: ios, facebook, data-modeling

In the talk [Facebook on iOS: Inside the "Big Blue App"](https://developers.facebooklive.com/videos/525/facebook-on-ios-inside-the-big-blue-app) Facebook is talking about a data model layer concept called **Mem Models**.

I find this concept quite interesting and I was wondering if Facebook is developing an open source library for it? Or what is the best way to use this concept? Do you have any info, tutorials or links to articles?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought that might be a interesting topic to discuss and that other people interested to know a bit more about it too. Where else can I ask questions like this?

Answer (score 1):

Slobodan says in the Q&A section (end of the video) that there is still a lot of work ahead of them before they will be able to release it and possibly opensource it just like they did with [AsyncDisplayKit](http://asyncdisplaykit.org/) or [ComponentKit](https://github.com/facebook/componentkit).

My guess is that it's something very similar to either [CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile) or [Realm.io](https://realm.io/).